Help with Stripe & React js please!
I need that when approving the payment it goes to the success route and the success route sends the form to email js, so that if the payment is not approved there is no way to enter the route and it is redirected to "/", or another way to do it This, please, I really need it!
//SiteLinksStep.jsx//

import React, { useState } from 'react'; import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'; import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js'; import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import "./SiteLinksStep.scss"

const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test');

const SiteLinksStep = ({ setStep, handleSubmit }) => { const { t } = useTranslation(); const navigate = useNavigate(); const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

const handleStripePayment = async () => { const stripe = await stripePromise; const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({ lineItems: [{ price: 'price', quantity: 1 }], mode: 'payment', successUrl: ${window.location.origin}/success, cancelUrl: ${window.location.origin}/cancel, });

if (error) {
  console.error('Stripe Error:', error);
  return false; // Pagamento falhou
}

// Salvar estado de pagamento aprovado no sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('payment', 'true');
return true; // Pagamento aprovado
};

const handleSubmitWithValidation = async (e) => { e.preventDefault(); setSubmitted(true);

const paymentSuccess = await handleStripePayment(); // Verifica se o pagamento foi aprovado
if (paymentSuccess) {
  handleSubmit(e, true); // Passa true indicando que o pagamento foi aprovado
}
};

const handleNormalSubmit = (e) => { e.preventDefault(); // Chame o handleSubmit com false para indicar que não houve pagamento handleSubmit(e, false); };

return ( <> {t('agree.confirmText')} {t('agree.submissionGuidelines')} {t('agree.agreement')} PAGAR PARA IR MAIS RÁPIDO

  <div className="step-buttons">
    <button onClick={() => setStep((prev) => prev - 1)} type='button' className="back-button">
      {t('agree.back')}
    </button>
    <button onClick={handleNormalSubmit} type='button'>
      {t('agree.submit')}
    </button>
  </div>
</>
); };

export default SiteLinksStep;

//SuccessPage.jsx//

import React, { useEffect } from 'react'; import emailjs from 'emailjs-com'; import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const SuccessPage = () => { const { t } = useTranslation();

useEffect(() => { const sendEmail = async () => { console.log("Iniciando o envio do email...");

  const myName = sessionStorage.getItem('myName');
  const email = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
  const profileLink = sessionStorage.getItem('profileLink');
  const siteName = sessionStorage.getItem('siteName');
  const description = sessionStorage.getItem('description');
  const category = sessionStorage.getItem('category');
  const tool = sessionStorage.getItem('tool');
  const price = sessionStorage.getItem('price');
  const features = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('selectedFeatures'));

  console.log("Dados preparados para envio:", { myName, email, siteName, hot });

  const templateParams = {
    from_name: myName,
    to_name: 'Paulo Vitor',
    profileLink,
    email,
    category,
    tool,
    siteName,
    description,
    sitePrice: price === '0' ? 'Free' : `$${price}`,
    features: features,
    hot:1
  };

  try {
    console.log("Enviando email...");
    await emailjs.send('service', 'template', templateParams, '');
    console.log('Email enviado com sucesso!');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro ao enviar o email:', error);
  }

  // Limpar o sessionStorage após o envio
  sessionStorage.clear();
};

sendEmail();
}, []);

return (


{t('success.title')}
{t('success.description')}

); };
export default SuccessPage;


Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original).
